# jQuery UI ToolTip Extra width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI tooltip which is enabled when I hover over a few images. I have attached a picture to this question. The white margin that we see after the pink is extra. Any idea why it is being formed ?
I am struggling for the past few hours to get the reason behind it. 
[tooltip example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfyPR.png)
    `HTML: This is my HTML content
    
    
    :

```
CSS: My CSS rules
.ui-tooltip {
        padding: 1em;
        border: 2px solid $colorBrown;
        color: $colorBrown;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .ui-tooltip-content {
        padding: 1em;
        color: $colorWhite;
        background: $colorBrown;
    }

    .ui-tooltip-content::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        border-style: solid;
        display: block;
        color: $colorBrown;
    }

    .top .ui-tooltip-content::after {
        bottom: -10px;
        left: 70px;
        border-color: $colorBrown transparent;
        border-width: 10px 10px 0;
    }

    JS: The JS function that initiates tooltip 
    function toolTipInit() {
        $('.social-icons span').tooltip({
            items: 'a.whatsapp, a.skype',
            content: function() {
                return $(this).data('content');
            },
            show: null,
            position: {
                my: 'center bottom',
                at: 'center top-50'
            },
            tooltipClass: 'top',
            open: function(event, ui) {
                if (typeof(event.originalEvent) === 'undefined') {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            close: function(event, ui) {
                ui.tooltip.hover(function() {
                        $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
                    },
                    function() {
                        $(this).fadeOut('400', function() {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    });
            }
        });
    }
    `
```

Comment: I don't see the picture you referenced in your question. Can you add it again.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have attached the picture now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use !important in your custom css so that it can override the default ui css. I think it will help.

Ex:

```
padding:0 !important;
```

Comment: How dumb can I be ? I have been working on this for so many years and yet get stuck in these basic things. Anyways, the !important worked just fine. Thank you so much buddy :)

Comment: happens sometime :)

keep asking and give up vote for correct answer :P

Comment: Yeah, it happens sometimes. Ill vote once stack overflow allows me to vote it.